# Listing files along with file format (unix or dos) on unix

Tags: linux, unix, file-format

File format of a file can be determined using
`:set ff?`
But for this i need to open the file and run above command.

If i have a large number of files, how can i display whether it is dos format or unix format file without opening the file?

Comment: `i need to open the file` with "what" do you "open the file"? `how can i display whether it is dos format or unix format file without opening the file?` Just `grep $'\r'` But it's not possible to do "without opening the file", to determine if a file _contains_ dos line endings, you have to read from it, thus you have to open it.

Comment: The file command will tell you without needing to open the file in vim.